# Datatable merge and rejectchanges not working as intended

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I'm working on a winform holding 2 similar datagrids, each one has its datasource set to a different instance of the same table. For testing purposes, the tables have both different and similar records with different cells being filled for each record.

1- When calling Datatable.Merge, the target table gets the missing rows, but the initial rows do not have their empty cells updated from the corresponding cells of the source table.

2- When calling Datatable.RejectChanges on the target table, the rows added by the merge are not removed, which is a problem, yet this time, the empty cells of the initial rows get properly updated from the corresponding cells of the source table, which I would expect to happen when merging.

The function used to fill tables:

```
private bool OpenFile(Datatable table)
{
    if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // OFD is OpenFileDialog
    {
        if (UserPrompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // UserPrompt is a custom input dialog for user credentials
        {
            try
            {
                // code to fill table not shown for readability, works well anyway
                table.AcceptChanges(); // otherwise all the records are deleted after RejectChanges, including the initial ones                        
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Operation Canceled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The merging function:

```
private void menuMerge1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table1.Merge(Table2, true);
    if (MessageBox.Show("Table 2 merged to table 1. Save changes? Choosing no will cancel the merging.", "Keep or Discard Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
        Save(Table1); // saving to file, custom function
    else Table1.RejectChanges();
}
```

The OpenFile function is called first, then the merge, that's it.

I have tried:

- Refresh the DataGridView.
- Reset the DataSource of the DataGridView.
- Call AcceptChanges on the target after the merge.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: I better approach would be to first ask the user & then proceed for merging rather than other way round. you will save on valuable processor time for large tables.

Comment: @Abdul Rehman Sayed: True. I will change this as soon as I find a reliable way to merge the tables :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, DataTable.Merge does not raise events, which means that RejectChanges will only work on modified rows, added rows are marked as Unchanged. Solution was to code a custom merge function. Works well with similar tables, assuming that the PK is first, single column:

```
    private bool Merge(DataTable target, DataTable source, bool preserve)
    {           
        if (!preserve)
        {
            target.Merge(source, false);
            return true;
        }            
        else
        {
            DataRow drTargetMatch;
            DataRow drNew;
            int numCol = source.Columns.Count;
            int index = 1;

            try
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in source.Rows)
                {
                    drTargetMatch = target.Rows.Find(dr[0]);
                    if (drTargetMatch == null) // source row does not exist in target, add a copy
                    {
                        drNew = target.NewRow();
                        drNew.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
                        target.Rows.Add(drNew);
                    }
                    else // source row exists in target, update empty values
                    {
                        for (index = 1; index < numCol; index++) // start at 1 since we don't update PK
                        {
                            if (drTargetMatch.IsNull(index) && !dr.IsNull(index))
                                drTargetMatch[index] = dr[index];                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Operation Canceled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                target.RejectChanges();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }                        
    }
```